# Binary Reading from and Writing to a File in C

Tags: c, binary

I need some help writing a program in C to reading and writing binary values from and to a file. For this program I do not need the entire contents of the file (2048 bytes) read in, only the first 30 halfwords.

I do know how to write a program to do this for text files, but am new to binary. Do I need to allocate memory like for text files? Would using a buffer be helpful? Are the commands similar or different to fprintf, sscanf, and other syntax things?

Comment: [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) and [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) are the functions you need to get familiar with.

Comment: And yes, of course you still have to allocate memory.

Comment: Also, open the file with mode `"rb"` rather than `"r"`. This tells the program not to translate newline characters to another format.

Comment: I edited your question to remove references to "hex" because binary is a format for storing data, while hex is merely a format for displaying it. If I misunderstood your question and your input file contains text representations of values in hex format, you can revert my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this example should work

```
#define FILE "file path"
#define LEN 30
int main()
{
    int read;
    char *buffer;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FILE, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("[-] CreateFile() failed.\n");
        return 0;}
    buffer = (char*)malloc(LEN);
    ReadFile(hFile, buffer, LEN, &read, NULL);
}
```

you read the file with no special flags. you mentioned you only need the first 30 halfwords which are obviously the first 30 bytes. `ReadFile()` has the `nNumberOfBytesToRead` parameter, so all you need to pass 30. If you want you could try to read an .exe file and print what you got. it should start with MZ and "this program cannot be run in dos mode" (you'd need to read more than 30 bytes in order to see all of it). Some NULL bytes wouldn't let you simply print it so you should try that way

```
int PrintBuffer(char *buffer)
{
    int written;
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteFile(out, buffer, LEN, &written, NULL);
    CloseHandle(out);
}
```

**edit : a version with no winapi**

```
#define PATH "file path"
#define LEN 30
#define HWORD 1
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(LEN);
    FILE *f = fopen(PATH, "rb");

    if(!f) printf("[-] fopen() failed.\n");
    else printf("[+] fopen() succeeded.\n");

    if(fread(buffer, HWORD, LEN, f) != LEN) printf("[-] fread() failed.\n");
    else printf("[+] fread() succeeded.\n");
```

and now printing the data without the NULL bytes cutting the output too early

```
    for(i = 0; i < LEN; i++) printf("%c", buffer[i]);
}
```

`fread()` reads "elements" from a file has the following parameters:
1. the buffer which will receive the read data.
2. the size of each element in bytes. Half word is a byte, so the size is 1.
3. the number of elements you want to read. in this case 30. 
4. the FILE* you used for `fopen()`.

the return value is the amount of elements successfully read, it should be 30.

Comment: The OP said nothing about Windows, so using the Win32 API isn't really a good answer. The C runtime library would work on any platform.

Comment: unfortunately i figured it out when i was at the end of writing my answer... i've decided to post it anyway in case it would help someone else with the same problem in a windows system.

Comment: You do realize you can edit your answer, right? Change all those Win32 calls to `fopen`, `fread` etc. and you've got yourself a decent answer. Add a couple lines of code to show how to access the data as half-words (I assume he means 16-bit ints) and you've got yourself a good answer I will upvote.

Comment: @CareyGregory i added a proper version.

Comment: To print to an output file can i just change the last print statement to      fprintf(output_filename, "%c", buffer[i]); ?  Otherwise, thank you very much this has been very helpful!

Comment: @erose it should work. make sure you open the file in the right mode

Comment: @erose forgot to say, upvote my answer if it helped you :)